# Randomly choose between three images

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, random

I want to make a random choice of one of three images, and I believe I should use `arc4random()`, but I can't be certain. Here is the simple code I have:

```
SPImage *image = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
SPImage *image1 = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
SPImage *image2 = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: What are you choosing between? All three of the images in your snippet seem to be created with the same texture.

Comment: what is the question its not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem Solved !!

This will do exactly what you want,

```
SPImage *image = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
SPImage *image1 = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:0]];
SPImage *image2 = [SPImage imageWithTexture:[balloonTextures objectAtIndex:0]];

NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image,image1,image2, nil];
int random = arc4random() % 3;

SPImage *myRandomImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:random];
```

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(3)` is a slightly better way to pick a number in a limited range.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image,image1,image2, nil];
SPImage *randomImage = [imgArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(3)];
```